# How to show the groupwise result for the following scenario?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unix-timestamp

I'm having a database table named `user_transaction` whose structure is as below:

```
transaction_id    mediumint(6)   UNSIGNED (PK)
transaction_no    varchar(55)
transaction_cc_avenue_no    varchar(55)
transaction_card_category    varchar(100)
transaction_user_id      varchar(32)
transaction_user_name    varchar(255)
transaction_user_email_id    varchar(255)
transaction_deal_code    varchar(10)
transaction_dc_id    smallint(4)
transaction_amount    float(10,2)
transaction_discount    float(10,2)
transaction_total_amount    float(10,2)
transaction_data_assign    enum('0', '1')
transaction_status    enum('success', 'inprocess', 'fail', 'cancelled')     
transaction_date    bigint(12)
transaction_update_date    bigint(12)
transaction_update_user_id    varchar(32)
```

I'm using UNIX Timestamp values to store the dates in the column `transaction_date`. Now I'm fetching two dates from the form in '`dd/mm/yyyy`' format, convert it in UNIX Timestamp and using it in a following query. Now I want to display the datewise no. of transactions of different transaction_status(i.e.Total transactions took place on each date,total no. of transactions of status 'success', 'inprocess', 'fail' and 'cancelled') for all the dates between the range I given. Those records should be grouped by transaction date. I tried a lot to get this result but not getting any success. For your reference I'm giving below my query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) `total count`, SUM(transaction_status = 'success') `success`, SUM(transaction_status = 'inprocess') `inprocess`, SUM(transaction_status = 'fail') `fail`, SUM(transaction_status = 'cancelled') `cancelled` FROM user_transaction WHERE transaction_date >= '1325376000' AND transaction_date <=  '1338422400' GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date)
```

Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `from_unixtime()` function creates date with a time on it.  You just want the date:

```
SELECT date(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date)),
       COUNT(*) `total count`, SUM(transaction_status = 'success') `success`, 
       SUM(transaction_status = 'inprocess') `inprocess`,
       SUM(transaction_status = 'fail') `fail`,
       SUM(transaction_status = 'cancelled') `cancelled`
FROM user_transaction
WHERE transaction_date >= 1325376000 AND transaction_date <= 1338422400
GROUP BY date(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date))
```

I also dropped the `'` from the number constants.  These are numbers so it is misleading to make them look like strings (doesn't affect performance, just the understandability of the query).

EDIT:

If you want to group by month:

```
SELECT year(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date))),
       month(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date))),
       COUNT(*) `total count`, SUM(transaction_status = 'success') `success`, 
       SUM(transaction_status = 'inprocess') `inprocess`,
       SUM(transaction_status = 'fail') `fail`,
       SUM(transaction_status = 'cancelled') `cancelled`
FROM user_transaction
WHERE transaction_date >= 1325376000 AND transaction_date <= 1338422400
GROUP BY year(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date))),
         month(date(FROM_UNIXTIME(transaction_date)))
```

You might need to change the `where` clause for the range of dates being included.

Comment: :Thank you so much once again. Your query really did the magic for me. Can you help me a bit more? In the above query the rsults are displayed datewise. Now I want to display the same results monthwise how should I achieve it? Means e.g. I want to display the monthwise results from Jan.2012 to June 2013

Comment: @phpLover . . . You can use the function `year()` and `month()` on the date or the function `date_format()`.  Be sure you put the same calls in the `group by` as in the `select`.

Comment: :Thanks for your suggestion. I tried your trick but it didn't work. May be I am doing something wrong. Can you provide me the query as an answer to this question. I'd be really grateful to you.